# Wundows 7 странная полоса загрузки в Explorer

Tags: windows-7

Доброго всем здравия.
Не судите строго, но админить ОСи забросил с приходом 7-ки.
Но вот дома с ПК твориться что-то странное.
Была ХР 32бит, с 3-мя Гб ОЗУ (так как +1Гб не понимала) и всё было нормально.
Поставил 7-ку (64бит) именно из-за ОЗУ в 4 Гб и начались траблы.
Каталоги через проводник открываются по 10-20 секунд!
Постоянно пикают колонки и замирает мышь на этих пиках.
И эта странная полоса загрузки?
что она значит?
[вот эта](http://icar-soft.ru/temp/load_line.jpg)

Comment: Идеально было бы купить SSD диск)

Answer (score 2):

Потестировать тебе компьютер надо. В первую очередь память и жесткий диск. А полоса загрузки означает прогресс загрузки элементов в "Установке / удалении программ")

Comment: @Денис Проскурин, ни добавить, не убавить)))@I_Car, причин может быть быть много и имя им легион... От проблем с жезками до "бяки" в системе...UP С [этойтемой][1] случайно не связано?[1]:http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/8042/firefox-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81-websearch-pur-esult-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-ff

Comment: Значит плюсуем мой ответ)

Comment: @zerglyn, нет, та проблема была несколько дней назад.А вот с 7-кой, сразу как поставил её.Комп не старый 1,5 годика, На ХРюне 32бит летал, но вот чёрт дёрнул докупить планку до 4 Гб ОЗУ и ещё вдобавок раздел C упал, вот и натянул на бедненького, это убогое одеяние от MS.(для справки где не смотрел всякие "центры управления полётами", все на ХР сидят.)@Денис Проскурин - А полоса загрузки она **везде**!Открываешь папку с 2-5 каталогами + 10 файликов в ней и тоже самое.Ведь в ХП такого не было.

Comment: А не связано ли это с ресурсоёмкостью Win7?  Ведь хп - 1-1,5 гб установленная, а 7-ка 10-15 Гб!  Ведь не просто так 15 ГБ сидят на винте.-------------Допустим по аналогии с ОС Android.  Если на девайсе стоит 2.x.x версия, то девайс летает.  А стоит поставить 4.x.x версию, всё... Всё тупит, игры не идут, тесты показывают падение производительности на 30%.

Comment: 7-ка хороша. Никаких сверхестественных багов там нет. 8-ка плоха, как в свое время виста. XP как бы ни была хороша, но от нее пора отказываться хотя бы потому что кончается ее срок поддержки. Начни с тестирования жесткого диска. Например программой hddscan (http://hddscan.com/) или какой либо другой - HD Tune Pro. 2-я платная, но я думаю ты справишься)

Comment: Кстати, драйвера то для железа ты все проставил?

Comment: 1. Странно HDD Scan запустился только v2.5 (for Win 2k\XP)  А v3.3 не запускается на win-7. (если только насильно не воткнуть совместимость, опять же с XP SP3).Большой процент секторов с чтением > 50ms.  Скорее всего винтик ужо пора менять...  (он IDE ещё)Это же опять всё заново!  2. Про дрова странный совет.  Какие дрова надо на винт?  Оси сами всегда их нормально определяют.  А остальные дрова какие могут повлиять на скорость ОСи?  Если только для VGA. Но без дров на VGA вряд ли кто-то юзает ПК.

Comment: Я написал для ЖЕЛЕЗА в целом, а не каких то отдельных частей. В частности на производительность основательно могут влиять драйвера для чипсета материнской платы. И это при том что виндовс хорошо определяет их автоматом.

Comment: @Денис Проскурин  Вот результат скан-теста режим "Verify":  [результат][1]  [1]: http://icar-soft.ru/temp/hdd.jpgЭто совсем плохой результат?

Comment: Батенька ТС... Что же вы хотите от машинки с IDE-шным веником под Win-7... Ваша "полоса загрузки" и есть то, что вы видите - полоса загрузки. Вы же не удивляетесь, дозвонившись на dial-up, что современные сайты не грузятся в две секунды, так? То же самое и тут - полоса загрузки в Win-7 есть У ВСЕХ, просто на более шустрых машинках человеку она не заметна. Так что не парьтесь - все у Вас пучком;)UPПо поводу проверок/тестов/... Прогоните веник Викторией, обратите внимание на параметр 05 - переназначенные сектора. Если их больше 100-150 - веник ОДНОЗНАЧНО под замену.

Comment: UP+Отсутствие бЭдов может и не отражать реального состояния поверхности. Просто система, при обнаружении, по ее мнению, плохого сектора, переназначает его. Вот если переназначенных становится много - это уже говорит о систематическом возникновении НОВЫХ "плохих". И, косвенно, о состоянии поверхности в целом.+, если веник уж начал сыпаться - то будет сыпаться по нарастающей. Особенность тех.процесса, чтоб ее...